# How do I make an SVG take no space in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Given an extremely simple SVG in a html file, such as this one:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    no space between here &gt;<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>&lt; and here.
  </body>
  
</html>
```

I want to put this in my HTML page as an overlay: I don't want it to take up any space in the DOM, and just appear in the background. How can I do this? I presume it's CSS but I can't figure out the right incantation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this helps:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  /* absolute positioning takes svg out of flow of the document, it is positioned relative to it's closest parent with 'relative' or 'absolute' positioning, in this case the body */
  position: absolute;
  /* setting this makes it so that the svg won't eat up any clicks meant for elements underneath it */
  pointer-events: none;
  
  /* you can use these offsets to change where exactly the svg is positioned */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
no space between here &gt;<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>&lt; and here.
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `position: absolute` to take it out of the page flow:

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    no space between here &gt;<svg height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>&lt; and here.
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, but did it wrong and concluded it did not work :( Thanks, I have it working now!